# Eliminating the duplicates completely in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have this code but it does not do what I want totally, I takes a list of tuples;

```
[(3,2),(1,2),(1,3),(1,2),(4,3),(3,2),(1,2)]
```

and gives

```
[(1,3),(4,3),(3,2),(1,2)]
```

but I want it to give

```
[(1,3),(4,3)]
```

where am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
eliminate :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
eliminate [] = []
eliminate (x:xs)
    | isTheSame xs x  = eliminate xs
    | otherwise       = x : eliminate xs


isTheSame :: [(Int,Int)] -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
isTheSame [] _ = False
isTheSame (x:xs) a
    | (fst x) == (fst a) && (snd x) == (snd a)  = True
    | otherwise                 = isTheSame xs a
```

Comment: What do you mean with "totally", why exactly should `(3,2)` and `(1,2)` be excluded?

Comment: I am searchin for a function that eliminates the duplicates completely, only the unique ones should be there, I guess I should change my implementation :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is *almost* correct. Just change this line

```
    | isTheSame xs x  = eliminate xs
```

to

```
    | isTheSame xs x  = eliminate $ filter (/=x) xs
```

The reason is that if `x` is contained in `xs`, you want to delete *all* occurences of `x`.

That said, there are a few parts in your code sample that could be expressed more elegantly:

- `(fst x) == (fst a) && (snd x) == (snd a)` is the same as `x == a`
- `isTheSame` is the same as `elem`, only with its arguments reversed

Thus, we could express the function `eliminate` like this:

```
eliminate [] = []
eliminate (x:xs)
  | x `elem` xs = eliminate $ filter (/=x) xs
  | otherwise = x : eliminate xs
```

Comment: ow yes! I was filtering that part to exclude x from the xs part but I was not able to manage it thank you :)

Comment: @Karavana: Check my edit, you should use `elem` instead of your custom, highly specialized `isTheSame` function (which also has a strange name)

Comment: I was just about to suggest that change.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15772150/2), you have just missed the grace period ;)

Comment: when I add filter part it gives "Instance of Eq [(Int,Int)] required for eliminate " error, what may cause this?

Comment: @Karavana That makes no sense. The code requires an `Eq` instance for `(Int,Int)`, but not for `[(Int,Int)]`. However, there is an `Eq` instance for both, `(Int,Int)` and `[(Int,Int)]`. Besides, that error message doesn't read like one from either ghc(i) or - if memory serves - from hugs. What implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using hugs, also I should say that my original code doesnot consist of homogeneous [(Int,Int)] type, but I am comparing just this two int values from [(Int,Int,Char,Char)] like model. I guess that is causing the error maybe?

Comment: @Karavana Tuples with more than 7 components? Then you need to write an instance (would work in ghci for tuples up to 15). Or, wait, you say you only use the two `Int`s as the criterion, so replace `elem` with a function `elemBy`.

Comment: exactly :( Unnfortunately I don't know how to do that. Well :/

Comment: @Karavana You define `consideredEqual :: -> Tuple -> Tuple -> Bool`. Then use that in `any consideredEqual list` (so `elemBy` would just be `any`, surprisingly I managed to type faster than I could think).

Comment: I got it worked at last :D with pattern matching, like you said I've created a function to get it filtered.

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
-- all possibilities of picking one elt from a domain
pick :: [a] -> [([a], a)]
pick []     = [] 
pick (x:xs) = (xs,x) : [ (x:dom,y) | (dom,y) <- pick xs]

unique xs = [x | (xs,x) <- pick xs, not (elem x xs)]
```

Testing:

```
*Main Data.List> unique [(3,2),(1,2),(1,3),(1,2),(4,3),(3,2),(1,2)]
[(1,3),(4,3)]
```

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14877448/849891) and in [Splitting list into a list of possible tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869097/splitting-list-into-a-list-of-possible-tuples/12872133#12872133)

---

Following [Landei's lead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15772304/849891), here's a *short* version (although it'll return its results sorted):

```
import Data.List

unique xs = [x | [x] <- group . sort $ xs]
```

Comment: good implementation Will, I appreciate your effort but I am interested in whats wrong with my implementation, but yours is perfect tho :)

Answer (score 4):

Inefficient reference implementation.

```
import Data.List

dups xs = xs \\ nub xs
eliminate xs = filter (`notElem` dups xs) xs
```

Answer (score 3):

A shorter version (but results will be sorted):

```
import Data.List

eliminate :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
eliminate = concat . filter ((== 1) . length) . group . sort
```

Or with `Maybe` (thank you, Marimuthu):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

eliminate = mapMaybe f . group . sort where f [x] = Just x; f _ = Nothing
```

Thinking about... we could use lists instead of `Maybe`:

```
import Data.List

eliminate = (>>= f) . group . sort where  f [x] = [x]; f _ = []
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using join instead of concat? By using concat, the import of Control.Monad is not necessary.

Comment: ```eliminate = mapMaybe f . group . sort where f [x] = Just x; f _ = Nothing``` since ```catMaybes . map f``` is simply ```mapMaybe f```

Comment: `[x | [x] <- group . sort $ xs]`. :)

Comment: thanks for the inspiration BTW (for the shorter variant).  I've added it to my answer. :)